Upgrade graphene-django to v3: 'Int cannot represent non-integer value"
I'm trying to upgrade graphene-django from 2.15.0 to 3.2.0.
After some fixes, I could get it to work, but while testing with the front-end, I start detecting errors of the type:
"Variable '$height' got invalid value '5'; Int cannot represent non-integer value: '5'"

Apparently graphene-django 2.15 can translate string arguments (in this case '5') into number values, but 3.2 it can't.
Is there a way to adapt the back-end so I don't have to change the front-end to correct the strings and turn them into numbers?
